# Magento 2 login customer programmatically without password

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, login, magento-ee

Need code for login customer programmatically without password in magento 2 enterprise edition?

If I have customer email id and I want to login without password in magento 1.X by code Here the code:

```
$email = 'test@m2s.com';
 $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
 $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
 $customer->loadByEmail(trim($email));
 Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());
```

But i want to use this in Magento 2 EE.

Any solution, Thanks in advance!

Comment: tried this extension? Available for enterprise too https://magecomp.com/magento-2-mobile-login.html

Answer (score 11):

First you need to use dependency injection to inject the following classes in your constructor

```
protected $_customer;
protected $_customerSession;

public function _construct(...
                         \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
                         \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession) {
    ...
    $this->_customer = $customer;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    ...
}
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
$customer = $this->_customer->loadByEmail("test@m2s.com"); 
$this->_customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

Comment: Could you please paste some sample code here

Comment: @AmalEThomas what do you mean? My answer is a code sample

Comment: I have android app, website for shopping, when the customer go to cart in shopping cart app, it will load the shopping cart to app from web. Here the customer don't want to login again. So i will  pass the customer email via url to login without password. I will have to use above script to load the cart page without login while load web cart page in app. 1) Where i have place this code?

Comment: @Rapheal, I am new to magento 2, Where and How i place this code sample?

Comment: @AmalEThomas well that's an entire module to develop here there's no short answer sorry

Comment: How to use dependency injection to inject above classes in constructor?

Comment: @AmalEThomas exactly the way I did you add the class defined variables to the constructor and assign them to protected variables that you can use later in your code

Comment: Where i have to place this "protected $_customer;
protected $_customerSession;

public function _construct(...
                         \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
                         \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession) {
    ...
    $this->_customer = $customer;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    ...
}"

Comment: @AmalEThomas in your custom class of your module

Comment: @AmalEThomas, are you using webview app for website ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I tried this approach on 2.1.9 and 2.2.5 using a custom controller and I can see account links dashboard update to display "My Account" link (probably because the CONTEXT_AUTH variable is set to true) but the moment I navigate to any other link the login links appear again. Is your session being maintained throughout any visited page?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow that [links](https://blog.willfeeling.com/2019/05/05/auto-login-without-password/) for login customer/admin without password:

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We can Magento 2 login customer using an external script. We need to create one external script and run it on the browser. We need to check this [Link](https://rb.gy/iayqoy)

Comment: Actual link target: https://www.trycoder.com/2021/01/login-customer-without-password.html. Gives certificate error. Wouldn't click on that.